# How can I install elementary OS on Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, ppa, elementary-theme

How can I install the components that make up elementary OS on Ubuntu?

Comment: what Ubuntu version are you using now?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 11.04 and windows 7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### For 12.04 (stable) only:

Use the following PPA:

```
ppa:elementary-os/stable
```

### For 12.04, 13.04, and 13.10 (unstable, daily updates):

Use the following PPA:

```
ppa:elementary-os/daily
```

---

Then update and install the elementary-desktop package.

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop
```

To login to your new eOS desktop, logout, and choose ***Pantheon*** as your session.

---

#### Optional extras:

Apps such as Birdie and Agenda can be found in another PPA:

```
ppa:versable/elementary-update
```

Comment: elementary-meta appears not to be available in that package... :s

Comment: @hayd I'll have to check to see what it has been renamed to. elementary from the daily PPA is a moving target, so package names change often.

Comment: Thanks! It's weird cos it appears in the list (on the daily ppa site) but isn't available to install (other elementary packages are). Perhaps it's a temporary problem?

Comment: @hayd what version of Ubuntu are you running? It may not be available for that version of Ubuntu.

Comment: I see this on both 13.04 and 13.10 "E: Unable to locate package elementary-meta", it's strange as it looks like it's built in the ppa https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/daily

Comment: elementary-desktop is not longer available in repository

Answer (score 4):

As complete as I can make it:

[Elementary OS](http://elementaryos.org/) (or Jupiter) needs to be installed like any other OS: you burn a CD.
Click the link and choose download or click these links for the [i386](http://sourceforge.net/projects/elementaryos/files/elementaryos0.1-jupiter-i386.iso/download) or for the [amd64](http://sourceforge.net/projects/elementaryos/files/elementaryos0.1-jupiter-amd64.iso/download).

From their [FAQ](http://elementaryos.org/faq/):

> How can I install Jupiter?
>   Simply burn the iso to a CD, or install it to a flash drive. Insert the CD or flash drive into your computer, then reboot and you should see the elementary installer which will guide you through the installation. If your computer won't boot to the CD or flash drive, you may need to change the related option in your computer's BIOS.

Default apps:

- Midori web browser
- Docky
- Dexter Contacts app
- Postler e-mail client
- Lingo dictionary
- Abiword word processor
- GNUmeric spreadsheet app
- Software Centre
- Shotwell
- Totem Movie Player
- Empathy
- Nautilus-Elementary

[Warning regarding Natty](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/using-elementary-os-or-other-ubuntu-derivatives-dont-upgrade-to-natty/):  "… users of elementary OS Jupiter may be prompted to upgrade to Ubuntu 11.04. We strongly urge you not to do so [...] because the upgrade process may render your install unusable."

[image: im1]
<sub>From omgubuntu</sub>

If you need this OS inside Ubuntu you can

1. Add [Virtualbox](http://packages.ubuntu.com/virtualbox) [image: Install virtualbox] and install Elementary OS inside virtualbox.
2. Create empty space on your hard disc (so a 3rd partition: ubuntu, windows, elementary) and triple boot.
3. Ubuntu 11.04 does not play nice with this OS. If you want 1 Ubuntu with elementary OS in it you need to use Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: i have seen people install elementary OS on ubuntu by using terminal. the whole operating system was changed

Comment: There is a reason why I asked what OS you are using: Ubuntu 11.04 and elementary OS do -not- play nice together. 11.04 changes in rather a lot of ways that do not work with lots of add-ons.
Have a look at this link: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/using-elementary-os-or-other-ubuntu-derivatives-dont-upgrade-to-natty/ regarding 11.04 and the warning on the Elementary OS site: http://elementaryos.org/psa/

Comment: can you dual boot with the OS? or use wubi

Comment: yes and yes! or use virtual box (that might be the best option ;) )

Comment: how do you do a triple partition

Comment: The same way you made the dual boot with ubuntu and windows? You create enough free space on your system and install it into that free space. Grub will make it a triple boot (you get 3 instead of 2 options). You create free space from within Ubuntu with gparted.

Answer (score 3):

Rinzwind's thorough answer is how you can get a stable 0.1 release of ElementaryOS that is based off of 10.10.

If you want to convert your 11.04 installation into a beta build of ElementaryOS, then the following steps will do that for you:

**WARNING: It is NOT advised to do this with anything but a clean installation of Natty.**

**Second Warning: This might not work for you at all since it is beta software. This WILL erase everything in your ~/Desktop folder. You WILL have to create a new user after this to complete the process. You have been warned.**

In a terminal one after another:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bzr 
bzr branch lp:elementaryos
cd ~/elementaryos
```

Last chance to back out here.
If you're sure you want to transform your Ubuntu 11.04 install into Elementary OS then run the last command:

```
sudo conf.sh --configure-installed
```

After this is done (it takes a while) create a new user in the Users Settings application. Restart your machine (logging out might work, but I would advise doing a full restart). I'm not 100% sure if you will have to log in to the new users account, but it seems likely.