# Ubuntu desktop 12.04 Desktop Environment customization

Tags: 12.04, unity, icons, user-management

I am a new Linux user, I want to accomplish the following settings of the followings

1. no Dash icon
2. no trash icon
3. no workspace switcher icon
4. In global menu bar, only show the current time, but can't modify
5. In global menu bar, the gear icon only show the shutdown option by user
6. Disable short cut key

Is it possible to do these on Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the default Unity DE offers many customization options. If you want something more flexible, I would suggest Xfce (or any other from [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)).

Comment: I agree. You would have to rewrite the Unity interface to pull off such a big modification of Unity. But there are plenty other interfaces out there for Ubuntu. XFCE and LXDE are very customizable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my configuration:

Install Xubuntu desktop

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

Install Chinese input method

```
sudo apt-get install ibus-table-quick
```

Set auto logon with user account:

Modify `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`:

```
  [SeatDefaults]
  autologin-user=< someuseraccount >
  autologin-user-time=0
  greeter-session-lightdm-gtk-greeter
  user-session=xubuntu
  allow-guest=false
```

Disable right click mouse:

```
xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 8 9 4 5 6 7 2 3"
```

Disable CTRL, ALT, SHIFT and F1 - F12 key:

Open the terminal, type the `xev` command to check current keyboard mapping

Type the following command to disable that you want

```
  xmodmap -e "keycode 37 = " #disable left control key
```

Firefox change to kiosk mode

- you can find it from firefox add-ons

Hope this can help you a little!

Answer (score 0):

The changes you are proposing are not easy to accomplish. I have a desktop like that using another environment, different from Unity, that is the default you find in ubuntu. This is Elementary OS Luna, based on Ubuntu 12.04. Everything that runs in that ubuntu version also runs here:

[image: http://elementaryos.org/img/home/2-big.png]

You should consider try another distro / session for what you are looking for. You can add an elementary session following several tutorials on the web. I made a post a while to add a session of EOS in Ubuntu in spanish though. You can check [How can I install elementary OS on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47527/how-can-i-install-elementary-os-on-ubuntu) and http://ubuntuportal.com/2012/05/install-elementary-desktop-environment-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts.html for further info.

This is my post if you are interested. I think google translate can make it understandable. http://rhoconlinux.wordpress.com/2013/08/02/rhoartescritorio-como-instalar-elementary-os-luna-dentro-de-ubuntu-en-5-pasos/